# React Native: render only once tab view

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have been using this plugin [react-native-tab-view](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view) and for my case i have 5 routes but all use the same component so its rendered five times the component and also have an api call that i have inside the component that its fired 5 times.So my question is if there is a way to render only the tab that i selected besides iam using the same component this is my code:

```
const FirstRoute = () => (
  <View>
    <PostsList />
  </View>
);

const initialLayout = {
  height: 0,
  width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
};

class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isData: true,
      index: 0,
      routes: [
        { key: 'first', title: 'Todos' },
        { key: 'second', title: 'Encontrados' },
        { key: 'third', title: 'Perdidos' },
        { key: 'four', title: 'Adopción' },
        { key: 'five', title: 'Seguidos' },
      ]
    };

  }

  _renderTabBar = props => (
    <TabBar
      {...props}
      scrollEnabled
      indicatorStyle={styles.indicator}
      style={styles.tabbar}
      tabStyle={styles.tab}
      labelStyle={styles.label}
    />
  );

  _renderScene = SceneMap({
    first: FirstRoute,
    second: FirstRoute,
    third: FirstRoute,
    four: FirstRoute,
    five: FirstRoute
  })

  _handleIndexChange = index => {
    this.props.selected_tab(index);
    this.setState({
      index,
    });
  }


  render() {
    return (

      <TabView
        navigationState={this.state}
        renderTabBar={this._renderTabBar}
        renderScene={this._renderScene}
        onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange}
        initialLayout={initialLayout}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: please follow the below link from the plugin you've used, it has mentioned the the details about your concern.
https://github.com/satya164/react-native-tab-view#lazy

Answer (score 0):

In the TabView add the lazy property.